# ini_set() throwing 500 that is not logged to Apache error log

Tags: php

The following call to `ini_set()` is throwing a 500 error that is not logged in the Apache error log. Why is that happening?

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to another directive further up. This is a reproducible example:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
```

The [`ini_set()` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) states that the ini property must be a string:

```
ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue ) : string
```

Hence, the combination ends in a 500. Running Apache, our server is not logging an error where I expect one to be. Maybe this is related to the `ini_set()` error, our error log is a custom filepath so maybe it is logged somewhere, or something else.

This is how to resolve the error:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '1'); // Must be string
```

Hopefully this helps someone find an answer to this slightly odd scenario.

Comment: Odd that you're not seeing an error logged; this should throw a `TypeError`, which if uncaught leads to a line like `PHP Error: Uncaught TypeError ... in file ... on line ....`. Maybe there's a custom exception handler somewhere that's catching it and not logging it to the normal log?

Comment: Definitely thought it was odd. There isn't a handler, just a custom path. It acts like it's ignoring ini settings perhaps?, I just didn't feel like debugging that aspect once I had the solution above.

Comment: The handler could be anywhere in the application - either with `set_exception_handler`, or just a `try { ... } catch(Throwable $e) { ... }` somewhere.

Comment: It could be the latter, although I would think (?) that would suppress the 500.

Comment: Depends what the handler does; it might well trigger the 500 status itself (e.g. with a call to `header()`, or some framework-specific mechanism), then render a custom error page rather than PHP's default blank white screen.

Comment: I think it's a misconfiguration of the error log somewhere, since it's no longer logging any other errors too. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Found the error log, I was looking in the parent directory since someone (probably yours truly) accidentally put an `error_log` file there. So, the common air gap problem. YMMV.